# Not receiving AppMessage callbacks when sending message inside a bluetooth connection event

Tags: asynchronous, bluetooth, callback, pebble-watch, pebble-appmessage

Title sums it up. Same question is [here](https://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/31237/not-receving-app-message-callbacks-nexus-5x-basalt-3-9-2-and-aplite-3-9-1). Posting on SO to see if I can get any help. I also made an [almost minimal project](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest) to demonstrate the problem I'm facing, so links that follow point to the piece of code being mentioned.

Nothing fancy on **what I'm currently doing:**

1. My watchface is [notified](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/pebble/src/pebble3_app.c#L123) that the bluetooth connection with the phone is up, using `.pebble_app_connection_handler`.
2. In that [bluetooth callback](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/pebble/src/pebble3_app.c#L63) I set up, I [send](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/pebble/src/pebble3_app.c#L65) a [message to the phone](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/pebble/src/pebble3_app.c#L48) using `app_message_outbox_send()`. When BT connection is up, of course.
3. My Android app has a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to these messages and [calls an `IntentService`](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcesarino/android/pebblebttest/PebbleBroadcastReceiver.java#L40).
4. This `IntentService` [calculates the data](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcesarino/android/pebblebttest/PebbleUpdateService.java#L38), [pushes it to the watch](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcesarino/android/pebblebttest/PebbleUpdateService.java#L39) and [sets itself to run again](https://github.com/davidcesarino/PebbleBtTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcesarino/android/pebblebttest/PebbleUpdateService.java#L47) after some time.

**What I expect**:

1. When the BT connection is up, the connection handler to be called.
2. `app_message_outbox_send()` return a value telling if the message initiation had any errors. Normally, this is `APP_MSG_OK`, but it can be `APP_MSG_BUSY`, and I'm perfectly aware of that.
3. The app message callbacks (`app_message_register_inbox_received` and friends) be called to indicate if the asynchronous process of sending message to phone really worked. This is stated in the [docs](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/AppMessage/#app_message_outbox_send).

**What I'm seeing**:

The expected steps happen when the watchface is loaded, because I trigger the update manually. However, when the update is triggered by a BT connection event, expected steps 1 and 2 happen, but not the step 3.

This is particularly aggravating when I get `APP_MSG_OK` in step 2, because I should reasonably expect that everything on the watch went OK, and I should prepare myself to receive *something* inside the app message callbacks. Basically, I'm told by the docs to wait for a call that *never* arrives.

**This happens 100% of the time**.

Thank you for any help. I have another solution that works, using the watch to keep track of the update interval, but I believe this one allows me to save more battery by making use of recent Android features.

Comment: If you come here after all these years wondering why this question isn't marked as answered, it is because I do not consider it answered satisfactorily. I believe it was a bug. For details, see the comments below the bounty[-automatically]-awarded answer below.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation :

> To also be notified of connection events relating to any PebbleKit
>   companion apps associated with this watchapp, also assign a handler to
>   the **pebblekit_connection_handler** field. This will be called when the
>   status of the connection to the PebbleKit app changes.

Maybe it is what you need

Comment: “allows you to determine whether the watch is connected to the _Pebble mobile app_ by subscribing to the `pebble_app_connection_handler` […] also allows you to determine if the Pebble watch can establish a connection to a _PebbleKit companion app_ by subscribing to the `pebblekit_connection_handler` […] this will return _true for Android_ anytime a connection with the _Pebble mobile app_ is established (since PebbleKit messages are routed through the Android app)” Source: https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Event_Service/ConnectionService/

Comment: Besides, just noticed that `connection_service_peek_pebblekit_connection` returns `true` even when bluetooth is off or I leave the watch disconnected in the Pebble app. Only `connection_service_peek_pebble_app_connection` seems to have any effect.